# Product List Toolbar for Wishlist

Tags: magento2.2, sorting, wishlist, pagination, toolbar

I want to add the toolbar from the product list to my wishlist to have the pagination and the sorter element.

So in my *wishlist_index_index.xml* I added the block *Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar* to the *customer.wishlist*.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also I copied some methods that are required for the toolbar from *Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct* to my wishlist Block which extends the default one. As you can see I changed the use statement Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection to Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection to match my needs.

```
<?php

namespace CustomVendor\Wishlist\Block\Customer;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist
{
    /**
     * Default toolbar block name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = Toolbar::class;

    /**
     * Wishlist constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $helperPool
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $pager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $helperPool,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $httpContext,
            $helperPool,
            $currentCustomer,
            $postDataHelper,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Add wishlist conditions to collection
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->setInStockFilter(true)
            ->setOrderByProductName('asc');
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Preparing global layout
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Wish List'));
    }

    /**
     * Before rendering html, but after trying to load cache
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $collection = $this->getWishlistItems();

        $this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        $collection->load();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add toolbar block from product listing layout
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    private function addToolbarBlock(Collection $collection)
    {
        $toolbarLayout = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();

        if ($toolbarLayout) {
            $this->configureToolbar($toolbarLayout, $collection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Toolbar block from layout or a default Toolbar
     *
     * @return Toolbar
     */
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();

        if (!$block) {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
        }

        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Get toolbar block from layout
     *
     * @return bool|Toolbar
     */
    private function getToolbarFromLayout()
    {
        $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();

        $toolbarLayout = false;

        if ($blockName) {
            $toolbarLayout = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        }

        return $toolbarLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    /**
     * Configures the Toolbar block with options from this block and configured product collection.
     *
     * The purpose of this method is the one-way sharing of different sorting related data
     * between this block, which is responsible for product list rendering,
     * and the Toolbar block, whose responsibility is a rendering of these options.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    private function configureToolbar(Toolbar $toolbar, Collection $collection)
    {
        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }
        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);
        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    }
}
```

When I load the site I get the following error:

```
[08-May-2018 15:52:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection::addAttributeToSort() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php:196
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag2/app/code/CustomVendor/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php(206): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar->setCollection(Object(Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection))
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag2/app/code/CustomVendor/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php(127): CustomVendor\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist->configureToolbar(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar), Object(Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag2/app/code/CustomVendor/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php(110): CustomVendor\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist->addToolbarBlock(Object(Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection))
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag2/vendor/magento/framew in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php on line 196
```

This is because I use another collection. How would you make any progress here? Or is there another way to include the toolbar that you would to prefer?

Answer (score 1):

You got this error cause this collection haven't addAttributeToSort as function to sort so this is a solution for pass this problem :

The first is override the class Wishlist or specify a new class in your layout.

- Override:

> app/code/yourcompany/Wishlist/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" type="yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" />
</config>
```

or

- Layout:

> wishlist_index_index.xml

```
<block class="yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::view.phtml" cacheable="false">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</block>
```

In your

> app/code/yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php

```
<?php 

namespace yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ToolbarModel;

/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @api
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    /**
     * Products collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param ToolbarModel $toolbarModel
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder
     * @param ProductList $productListHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        ToolbarModel $toolbarModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        ProductList $productListHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $catalogSession, $catalogConfig, $toolbarModel, $urlEncoder, $productListHelper, $postDataHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Set collection to pager
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_collection->setInStockFilter(true);
        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int) $this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }

        if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'position') {
            $this->_collection->setOrder('added_at', $this->getCurrentDirection());

        } else {
            $this->setOrderByProductAttribute($this->_collection, $this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets ordering by product name
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setOrderByProductAttribute($collection, $attribute, $dir)
    {
        $productOrderId = [];

        $collectionproduct = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array($collection->getColumnValues('product_id'))))
            ->addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir)->load();

        foreach ($collectionproduct as $productOrdering) {
            $productOrderId []= $productOrdering->getEntityId();
        }
        return $this->_collection->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(product_id,'" . implode(",",$productOrderId) . "')");
    }
}
```

In your

> app/code/yourcompany/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php

```
<?php


namespace yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Customer;

use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection;
use yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist
{
    /**
     * Default toolbar block name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = Toolbar::class;

    /**
     * Wishlist constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $helperPool
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $pager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $helperPool,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $httpContext,
            $helperPool,
            $currentCustomer,
            $postDataHelper,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Add wishlist conditions to collection
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection($collection)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Wishlist Product Items collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection
     */
    public function getWishlistItems()
    {
        if ($this->_collection === null) {
            $this->_collection = $this->_createWishlistItemCollection();
            $this->_prepareCollection($this->_collection);
        }

        return $this->_collection;
    }

    /**
     * Before rendering html, but after trying to load cache
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $collection = $this->getWishlistItems();

        $this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        $collection->load();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add toolbar block from product listing layout
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    private function addToolbarBlock(Collection $collection)
    {
        $toolbarLayout = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();
        if ($toolbarLayout) {
            $this->configureToolbar($toolbarLayout, $collection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Toolbar block from layout or a default Toolbar
     *
     * @return Toolbar
     */
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();

        if (!$block) {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
        }

        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Get toolbar block from layout
     *
     * @return bool|Toolbar
     */
    private function getToolbarFromLayout()
    {
        $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();

        $toolbarLayout = false;

        if ($blockName) {
            $toolbarLayout = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        }

        return $toolbarLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    /**
     * Configures the Toolbar block with options from this block and configured product collection.
     *
     * The purpose of this method is the one-way sharing of different sorting related data
     * between this block, which is responsible for product list rendering,
     * and the Toolbar block, whose responsibility is a rendering of these options.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    private function configureToolbar(Toolbar $toolbar, Collection $collection)
    {
        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }
        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    }

}
```

In your layout

> wishlist_index_index.xml

```
     <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist">
        <block class="yourcompany\Wishlist\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Wishlist::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

We load the collection with the good sorting in our toolbar.php but the foreach reinitialise it, so we must pass by the variable goodorder for keep the order...

In your

> app/design/yourcompany/theme/Magento_Wishlist/item/list.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items $block
 *
 */
$columns = $block->getColumns();

$goodOrder = $block->getItems()->getData();
?>
<div class="products-grid wishlist">
    <?php $iterator = 1;?>
    <?php if (count($block->getItems())): ?>
    <ol class="product-items">
        <?php foreach ($goodOrder as $item): ?>
        <?php $item = $block->getItems()->getItemByColumnValue("product_id", $item['product_id']);?>
        <?=/* @noEscape */($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li data-row="product-item" class="product-item" id="item_' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) . '">' : '</li><li class="product-item" id="item_' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($item->getId()) . '">'?>
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                    <?=$column->setItem($item)->toHtml()?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>
        <?=($iterator == count($block->getItems()) + 1) ? '</li>' : ''?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ol>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="message info empty">
            <span><?=$block->escapeHtml(__('This Wish List has no Items'))?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <?=$column->getAdditionalHtml()?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

In your view.phtml of the module or template:

> app/design/yourcompany/theme/Magento_Wishlist/templates/view.phtml

You need add in the code the next:

```
<div class="toolbar--top">
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
...
...
<div class="toolbar--bottom">
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I complete all above steps but when i select any value from sort dropdown, no product loads on page but shows this error in log. [2021-02-25 09:20:12] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'product_id' in order clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `wishlist_item` AS `main_table`